# Wallet Connect does not send proposal connecting on same host

Tags: walletconnect

I am asking this question because I am building a mock interface to do a mock to test the behavior of my implementation. For this I am using `@walletconnect/web3wallet": "^1.9.5` and `@web3modal/ethers": "^3.5.7` in the same host. Normally I used the Web3 Wallet to connect to other dApps and it worked just fine, but now, trying to connect to the Web3 Modal on the same host, I am not receiving the proposal after doing the pairing with the URI, there is no error but just the process does not continue.

I can now independently both systems work just fine, as I can use Web3 Wallet with other dApps and because of I can connect to the web3 Modal from the same code I have in local but in another instance (staging).

I have searched and found two related issues:

1. https://github.com/WalletConnect/walletconnect-monorepo/issues/2975
2. https://github.com/orgs/WalletConnect/discussions/2868

And in one of them it is told that this is a behavior that latest versions should have.

I would really appreciate some assistance and clarification here.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/orgs/WalletConnect/discussions/4196

I found this post where it is said that the local variables are the same, thus, this behavior is not supported at the moment.